# Calculate ratios of all column combinations from a dataframe

Tags: r, function

I have a CVS file imported as df in R. dimension of this df is 18x11. I want to calculate all possible ratios between the columns. Can you guys please help me with this? I understand that either 'for loop" or vectorized function will do the job. The row names will remain the same, while column name combinations can be merged using paste. However, I don't know how to execute this. I did this in excel as it  is still a smaller data set. A larger size will make it tedious and error prone in excel, therefore, I would like to try in R.

Will be great help indeed. Thanks. Let's say below is the data frame as subset from my data.

```
dfn = data.frame(replicate(18,sample(100:1000,15,rep=TRUE)))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried following, it works, but if there is an alternative solution please do let me know.

Comment: rdfn = do.call(cbind,lapply(1:ncol(dfn[]),function(x) {
  DF = data.frame(dfn[,]/dfn[,][,x] );
  colnames(DF)=paste0(colnames(dfn[,]),"/",colnames(dfn[,])[x]); 
  return(DF)}))

Comment: @Dharmesh are you needing it in a different format?

Comment: Your code below will do the job. I just wanted to have an alternative that is structurally less complex. I am trying to learn about how to code efficiently for my data analysis work. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you do:

```r
do.call("cbind", lapply(seq_along(dfn), function(y) apply(dfn, 2, function(x) dfn[[y]]/x)))
```

You will get an array that is 15 * 324, with 18 columns representing all columns divided by the first column, 18 columns divided by the second column, and so on.

You can keep track of them by labelling the columns with the following names:

```
apply(expand.grid(names(dfn), names(dfn)), 1, paste, collapse = " / ")
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Much cleaner than one I posted in the comment above.

Comment: Update: Hey Allan, the names obtained by second code is slightly incorrect as the "numerator appears as denominator" and "denominator appears as numerator".