# How to calculate ratios and normalized ratios in all possible combinations in R?

Tags: r, combinations, tidyverse

I want to calculate normalised ratios and simple ratios in all possible combinations in R. This is the sample dataset

```
df = structure(list(var_1 = c(0.035, 0.047, 0.004, 0.011, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.024), var_2 = c(0.034, 0.047, 0.004, 0.012, 0.01, 0.011, 0.025
), var_3 = c(0.034, 0.047, 0.006, 0.013, 0.011, 0.013, 0.026), 
    var_4 = c(0.034, 0.046, 0.008, 0.016, 0.014, 0.015, 0.028
    ), var_5 = c(0.034, 0.046, 0.009, 0.017, 0.015, 0.016, 0.029
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

I could able to calculate simple ratios in all possible combinations after taking help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60617444/calculate-ratios-of-all-column-combinations-from-a-dataframe).

```
do.call("cbind", lapply(seq_along(df), function(y) apply(df, 2, function(x) df[[y]]/x)))
```

But I am unable to calculate normalised ratios i.e. (xj - xi)/(xj + xi) and how to name each calculated ratios properly?

Comment: How about replacing `df[[y]] / x` with `(df[[y]] - x)/(df[[y]] + x)`

Comment: I will try it. How to name the columns of the output properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, you can try nested `lapply` to get all the combinations :

```
cols <- 1:ncol(df)
mat <- do.call(cbind, lapply(cols, function(xj) 
          sapply(cols, function(xi) (df[, xj] - df[, xi])/(df[, xj] + df[, xi]))))
```

To assign column names, we can use `outer`

```
colnames(mat) <-  outer(names(df), names(df), paste0)
```

---

Thinking about it I think we can directly manipulate this using column indexes.

```
cols <- 1:ncol(df)
temp <- expand.grid(cols, cols)
new_data <- (df[,temp[,2]] - df[,temp[,1]])/(df[,temp[,2]] + df[,temp[,1]])
```

Comment: Can we have a separator like "," in `outer` function?

Comment: `outer(names(df), names(df), paste, sep = ",")` ?

Comment: For a small dataset it works fine. But I am having a large dataset (400 x 2150) which is taking a very long time. Can you provide some way out for large dataset?

Comment: I think we can just manipulate column index to do this. See updated answer if it helps.

Comment: Again it is taking long time to calculate and my system is getting hang. My system is having 16 GB RAM with Intel i7 processer. Should I ask a new question?

Comment: I was hoping the updated solution should have been faster but you have 2150 columns which means you'll have 2150 * 2150 i.e 4622500 columns in the output. Are you sure you want so many columns? Perhaps, it is better to ask a new question since this question will not get much visibility now.

Comment: I have asked a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62932491/how-to-calculate-normalized-ratios-in-all-possible-combinations-efficiently-for)

Answer (score 2):

We could do this more easily with `outer` alone

```
f1 <- function(i, j) (df[, i] - df[, j])/(df[, i] + df[, j])
out <- outer(seq_along(df), seq_along(df), FUN = f1)
colnames(out) <- outer(names(df), names(df), paste0)
```

Comment: I have tried your solution. I am having a large dataset (400 x 2150) which is taking a very long time. Can you provide some way out for large dataset?

Comment: @BappaDas `outer` in general should be faster than the nested `lapply/sapply` or `expand.grid`.  If that also takes too much time, then you may need to write this in Rcpp