# How to calculate normalized ratios in all possible combinations efficiently for a large matrix in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, combinations, rcpp

I want to calculate normalised ratios in all possible combinations efficiently for a large matrix in R. I have asked a similar question earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62915303/how-to-calculate-ratios-and-normalized-ratios-in-all-possible-combinations-in-r/62916359?noredirect=1#comment111283856_62916359) and with a small data and the solutions provided there worked fine. But when I am trying to apply the same solution for a large dataset (400 x 2151), my system is getting hang. My system is having 16 GB RAM with Intel i7 processer. Here is the code with data

```
df <- matrix(rexp(860400), nrow = 400, ncol = 2151)
```

Solution provided by @Ronak Shah

```
cols <- 1:ncol(df)
temp <- expand.grid(cols, cols)
new_data <- (df[,temp[,2]] - df[,temp[,1]])/(df[,temp[,2]] + df[,temp[,1]])
```

Or the following solution as provided by @akrun

```
f1 <- function(i, j) (df[, i] - df[, j])/(df[, i] + df[, j])
out <- outer(seq_along(df), seq_along(df), FUN = f1)
colnames(out) <- outer(names(df), names(df), paste, sep = "_")
```

Both the solutions taking a very long time and the system is getting hang. So, how can I efficiently do it?

**Update**

Upadate on expected output

```
library(tidyverse)

#Fake dataset
df = structure(list(var_1 = c(0.035, 0.047, 0.004, 0.011, 0.01, 0.01, 0.024), 
                    var_2 = c(0.034, 0.047, 0.004, 0.012, 0.01, 0.011, 0.025), 
                    var_3 = c(0.034, 0.047, 0.006, 0.013, 0.011, 0.013, 0.026), 
                    var_4 = c(0.034, 0.046, 0.008, 0.016, 0.014, 0.015, 0.028), 
                    var_5 = c(0.034, 0.046, 0.009, 0.017, 0.015, 0.016, 0.029)), 
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

cols <- 1:ncol(df)
mat_out <- do.call(cbind, lapply(cols, function(xj) 
  sapply(cols, function(xi) (df[, xj] - df[, xi])/(df[, xj] + df[, xi]))))

colnames(mat_out) <-  outer(names(df), names(df), paste, sep = ",")

y <- read.table(text = "s_no    y
1   95.512
2   97.9
3   92.897
4   94.209
5   87.472
6   91.109
7   92.83", header = T)

mat_out %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  left_join(y, by = c("id" = "s_no")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(y, id)) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(correl = cor(value, y, use = "complete.obs")) %>% 
  distinct(name, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  separate(name, c("Wav1", "Wav2"), sep = ",") %>% 
  select(-c("id", "y", "value")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Wav2, values_from = correl)

#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>   Wav1   var_1  var_2  var_3  var_4  var_5
#>   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 var_1 NA     -0.190 -0.358 -0.537 -0.551
#> 2 var_2  0.190 NA     -0.322 -0.528 -0.544
#> 3 var_3  0.358  0.322 NA     -0.682 -0.667
#> 4 var_4  0.537  0.528  0.682 NA     -0.595
#> 5 var_5  0.551  0.544  0.667  0.595 NA
```

Comment: The issue is that `expand.grid` and `outer` produce huge objects for larger vectors. As a result, a lot of time is spend with memory management (and you can easily run out of memory). In such a case, the most efficient and easiest solution is a simple C++ double `for` loop written with Rcpp.

Comment: @Roland I am not much familiar with Rcpp, can you please help me out?

Comment: Well, after rereading your question: Do you really need to store the result for all possible combinations? Have you calculated how many combinations that are?

Comment: I think it will be 2151*2151 = 4626801 combinations. Yes, I need to store the result for all possible combinations for further calculation.

Comment: Depending on the further calculation, you might not need to store them. Anyway, yes, use Rcpp.

Comment: I want to `left_join` another vector to the calculated combinations then convert it into long format then want to calculate the correlation. For correlation, I need to store the result for all possible combinations. Ofcourse, after that I will use `distinct` to keep unique combinations only.

Comment: As @Roland suggests, you can try a custom `Rcpp` solution. However, I believe it will not matter as generating them all will still require a large amount of storage. You will see that if you rolled your own `Rcpp` solution, you will have `NumericMatrix mat(400,  4626801)` somewhere in your code. This line alone takes my computer about 10 seconds to run. And that is just default initialization. Doing any sort of manipulating will surely not be efficient. A different approach is needed or you will need access to a beefy machine either way.

Comment: You can always store an index of the combination and compute the values on the fly. Also not that 1-2 is the same as 2-1 upto the sign. You can consider asking the question with Rcpp tag if you need to speed up things

Comment: @onyambu Can you help me out by answering this question?

Comment: Also note that You really dont have to calculate A-B if you have calculated B-1. also no need of A-A=0. so for 2151 columns, you can have 2312325 computations instead of 4626801 computation column. That is way handy.

Comment: Does the answer given not solve the issue?

Comment: No, not exactly.

Comment: What do you want to do with the results in the end? Storing that large matrix needs alot of memory. Either compute the values on the fly or just solve everything within the loop

Comment: I want to `left_join` another vector to the calculated combinations then convert it into long format then want to calculate the correlation. For correlation, I need to store the result for all possible combinations. Of course, after that I will use distinct to keep unique combinations only.

Comment: Can you show exactly what you mean? Cant you calculate the correlations? eg give a small example. Probably we can skip the matrix storing part and just get the correlations

Comment: @onyambu I have updated my question with a small example. Please see it.

Comment: Whatever you are doing. Does `structure(combn(df, 2, \(x)cor(RWC$RWC, c(diff(t(x))/rowSums(x)))), class='dist', Size = ncol(df))` solve it? ie it gives the lower matrix. You can use `as.matrix(...)` to create the matrix. Although I am not doing that because the upper triangle should be negative of the lower triangle

Comment: Do not try the code in the big data. Use the small data

Comment: Yes, the output is same with the code you have provided.

Comment: I believe you can now easily convert to C++ code. Also if you are responding to anyone, consider including the @name so that they are notified

Comment: @onyambu Actually, I am not much familiar with C++ or Rcpp.

Comment: I believe someone will come to your aid. If you need some private help, you can visit my page

Comment: The above data in a dirty c++ takes around 15 seconds. That is quite a leap

Comment: @onyambu For the small data or the big one?

Comment: 15 seconds for the big data.

Comment: Wow! That's great.

Comment: Using armadillo takes 15 seconds but using the STL takes 6 seconds. ie twice as fast. Also note that You can still optimize further

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: No, not yet. I don't have any idea about c++ or armadillo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rcpp` to make your code faster:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("
  std::vector<double> my_fun(arma::mat& x, arma::vec& y){
    int p = x.n_cols - 1;
    std::vector<double> result;
    for(int i = 0; i<p; i++){
      auto m = (x.cols(i+1, p).each_col() - x.col(i));
      m /= (x.cols(i+1, p).each_col() + x.col(i));
      auto a = arma::conv_to<std::vector<double>>::from(arma::cor(m, y));
      result.insert(result.end(), a.begin(), a.end());
    }
      
   return result;
}", 'RcppArmadillo')

my_fun(df, y) # takes approximately 14seconds.
```

You could use the STL functions to make it even faster. Though the code will be longer. on my computer this takes 6seconds

```
mat <- matrix(rexp(860400), nrow = 400, ncol = 2151)
y <- rnorm(nrow(df), 700, 10)

my_fun(mat, y) # This works
```

Comment: It is returning me ```Error in my_fun(as.matrix(df), y) : 
  Not compatible with requested type: [type=list; target=double].```. The df is a `data.frame`  and y is a `vector`.

Comment: @BappaDas your `df` should be a matrix. Not a dataframe

Comment: Even with matrix, I am getting the same error. Cna you please show me with an example data that the function is running?

Comment: @BappaDas check the edit

Comment: Now it is working. But how to make the output like my small example output?

Comment: @BappaDas just wrap the results in a dist element. Ie `as.matrix(structure(results, class='dist', Size = ncol(df)))`

Comment: If we want to calculate the ratio like `xj/xi`, how can we do that?

Comment: @BappaDas what do you mean by `xi/xj`?

Comment: In place of `function(i, j) (df[, i] - df[, j])/(df[, i] + df[, j])`, I want to calculate `function(i, j) (df[, j])/(df[, i])`

Comment: @BappaDas change `m` `m = x.cols(i+1, p).each_col()/ x.col(i)`

Answer (score 1):

Since memory seems to be your main issue, how about using iterators? Using the package **`RcppAlgos`<sup>*</sup>**, we can make use of `permuteIter` to calculate your ratios ***N*** at a time.

If one must have names, we need an additional iterator. This means you must keep 2 iterators in sync, which can become tedious. Fortunately, with the `summary()` methods of `permuteIter`, we can always see what the current index is and reset them with a wide range of options (e.g. random access `[[`, `front()`, `back()`, or `startOver()`).

```
library(RcppAlgos)
df <- matrix(rexp(860400), nrow = 400, ncol = 2151)

ratioIter <- permuteIter(ncol(df), 2, FUN = function(x) {
    (df[, x[2]] - df[, x[1]]) / (df[, x[2]] + df[, x[1]])
})

## if you really want to name your output, you must have
## an additional name iterator... not very elegant
nameIter <- permuteIter(paste0("col", 1:ncol(df1)), 2, FUN = function(x) {
    paste0(rev(x), collapse = "_")
})

firstIter <- matrix(ratioIter$nextIter(), ncol = 1)
firstName <- nameIter$nextIter()
colnames(firstIter) <- firstName

head(firstIter)
      col2_col1
[1,]  0.2990054
[2,] -0.9808111
[3,] -0.9041054
[4,]  0.7970873
[5,]  0.8625776
[6,]  0.2768359

## returns a list, so we call do.call(cbind
next5Iter <- do.call(cbind, ratioIter$nextNIter(5))
next5Names <- unlist(nameIter$nextNIter(5))
colnames(next5Iter) <- next5Names

head(next5Iter)
       col3_col1  col4_col1   col5_col1  col6_col1  col7_col1
[1,] -0.28099710  0.1665687  0.40565958 -0.7524038 -0.7132844
[2,] -0.81434900 -0.4283759 -0.89811556 -0.8462906 -0.5399741
[3,] -0.02289368  0.4285012  0.05087853 -0.5091659 -0.2328995
[4,] -0.06825458  0.3126928  0.68968843 -0.2180618  0.6651785
[5,]  0.33508319  0.7389108  0.84733425  0.9065263  0.8977107
[6,]  0.61773589  0.3443120  0.61084584  0.5727938  0.3888807
```

You should note that this does not show results where `i == j` (these give `NaN`). So the total number is just under 2151<sup>2</sup> (In fact it is exactly equal to `2151^2 - 2151`).

```
ratioIter$summary()
$description
[1] "Permutations of 2151 choose 2"

$currentIndex
[1] 6

$totalResults
[1] 4624650

$totalRemaining
[1] 4624644
```

There are even random access and previous iterators as well:

```
## Get the last ratio
lastIter <- ratioIter$back()
lastName <- nameIter$back()
mLast <- matrix(lastIter, ncol = 1)
colnames(mLast) <- lastName

head(mLast)
     col2150_col2151
[1,]      -0.6131926
[2,]       0.9936783
[3,]       0.1373538
[4,]       0.1014347
[5,]      -0.5061608
[6,]       0.5773503

## iterate backwards with the previous methods
prev5Iter <- do.call(cbind, ratioIter$prevNIter(5))
prev5Names <- unlist(nameIter$prevNIter(5))
colnames(prev5Iter) <- prev5Names

head(prev5Iter)
     col2149_col2151 col2148_col2151 col2147_col2151 col2146_col2151 col2145_col2151
[1,]     -0.75500069     -0.72757136     -0.94457988     -0.82858884     -0.25398782
[2,]      0.99696694      0.99674084      0.99778638      0.99826472      0.95738947
[3,]      0.27701596      0.45696010      0.00682574      0.01529448     -0.62368764
[4,]     -0.09508689     -0.90698165     -0.38221934     -0.41405984      0.01371556
[5,]     -0.31580709     -0.06561386     -0.07435058     -0.08033145     -0.90692881
[6,]      0.82697720      0.86858595      0.81707206      0.75627297      0.46272349

## Get a random sample
set.seed(123)
randomIter <- do.call(cbind, ratioIter[[sample(4624650, 5)]])

## We must reset the seed in order to get the same output for the names
set.seed(123)
randomNames <- unlist(nameIter[[sample(4624650, 5)]])
colnames(randomIter) <- randomNames

head(randomIter)
     col1044_col939 col20_col1552 col412_col2014 col1751_col1521 col337_col1295
[1,]     -0.3902066     0.4482747   -0.108018200      -0.1662857     -0.3822436
[2,]     -0.2358101     0.9266657   -0.657135882       0.0671608     -0.6821823
[3,]     -0.7054217     0.8944720    0.092363665       0.2667708      0.1908249
[4,]     -0.1574657     0.2775225   -0.221737223       0.3381454     -0.5705021
[5,]     -0.4282909    -0.4406433    0.092783086      -0.7506674     -0.1276932
[6,]      0.9998189    -0.2497586   -0.009375891       0.7071864     -0.2425258
```

Lastly, it is written in `C++` so it is very fast:

```
system.time(ratioIter$nextNIter(1e3))
#  user  system elapsed 
#     0       0       0
```

<sup>*</sup> I am the author of `RcppAlgos`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am unable to comprehend what should I change to get the output and how to name the output columns properly so that I can backtrack the combinations?

Comment: @BappaDas I showed an example of obtaining the output via `do.call(bind`. The names are trivially obtained with similar logic. I have updated my answer but it's not my preferred way of doing it. Getting names is nice but it really dirties the approach.

Comment: How to get the output for whole data? Your answer shows only 5 iterations.

Comment: Yes, that is the purpose of iterators. You create a few at a time and do what you need with them. As has already been explained, `outer` and `expand.grid` are plenty efficient speed wise, however generating an object as large as the one in your example is indicative that your approach needs to change. Your original approach will require a massive amount of memory. This is why I suggested using iterators. If you really need them all, you can always call `nextRemaining()`. I highly recommend reading the docs and rethinking your approach. Hope this helps.